# How Do I Use ES import in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

If I try to load a script with `type='module'`, Electron throws

`Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

I tried changing `npm start` to `electron --experimental-modules .` and `"type": "module"` in the package.json as you would in Node 12, but that didn't work either. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. but you can use `webpack` to pre-compile your ES code before you use in Electron.

so it becomes a question about `webpack` and `Electron` how to cooperate